# SVN and GNOME Keyring

Tags: svn, gnome-keyring

How to fix the following issue:

```
    $ svn update
    Password for 'default' GNOME keyring: 
    svn: GNOME Keyring is locked and we are non-interactive
```

I have googled around but can't seem to find a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 32):

Edit the  `~/.subversion/config` with `gedit` or `nano` ,  and add the following

```
[auth] 
password-stores =
```

then save and try again. All the best.

[credit](http://subversion.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1065&viewType=browseAll&dsMessageId=2402527#messagefocus)

Comment: can you considering accept ?

Comment: Unfortunately, adding this line gives me: `svn: ~/.subversion/config:17: Option expected` and `svn` refuses to proceed... what worked for me was `mv ~/.gnome2/keyrings/login.keyring ~/.gnome2/keyrings/_login.keyring` as per [Being prompted for '(null)' GNOME keyring - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159078/being-prompted-for-null-gnome-keyring); but then SVN insists on storing the password, once it passes, to a new Gnome keyring - which I don't want (I want to be asked each time, as when I use SVN over ssh), but that's another issue...

Comment: You have moved the the file from where currently gnome will fetch. so its keep on asking everytime.

Comment: It's worth nothing that this means disabling the encrypted storage of SVN passwords which you might not want to do.

Answer (score 5):

run the below command:

```
seahorse
```

and then delete all items in the menu.
The problem wil be gone

Comment: This was very helpful for a similar problem where svn would hang. Running seahorse showed me that the keyring was locked. Unlocked it, and svn is back to normal.

Answer (score 4):

## Solution 1

In my case the problem persisted until I deleted the *default* keyring. Using Mate Linux you can use this command to delete the default key file:

```
rm ~/.config/mate/keyrings/default
```

That solved the problem for me...

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions googled (removing keyrings from ~/.gnome2, blanking password-stores from ~/.subversion/config, ...) worked for me. I had to unset environment variables GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL GNOME_KEYRING_PID in my startup files (~/.xsession or whatever) in order to prevent their values being inherited from the desktop/login environment.